# How to disable contextual tab menu in officejs

Tags: office-js, contextmenu, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I want to **disable** the **menu** of the **ribbon**. I tried the below code but it's showing an **error** that **RichApi.Error: ControlIdNotFound**.
I'm executing the code on button click.
Is my hierarchy structure wrong for updating the ribbon?
I had tried the below code.

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>1122693b-5988-46ad-8554-c066770cd6fb</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="context-menu" />
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started." />
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help" />
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides"
    xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <Runtimes>
          <Runtime resid="Taskpane.Url" lifetime="long" />
        </Runtimes>
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="GetStarted.Title" />
            <Description resid="GetStarted.Description" />
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" />
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="Taskpane.Url" />
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">
            <OfficeMenu id="ContextMenuCell">
              <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="myMenu">
                <Label resid="CommandsGroup.Label" />
                <Supertip>
                  <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                </Icon>
                <Items>
                  <Item id="myMenuItemID">
                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="CommandsGroup.Label" />
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                    </Action>
                  </Item>
                </Items>
              </Control>
            </OfficeMenu>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"
          DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812" />
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!" />
        <bt:String id="CommandsGroup.Label" DefaultValue="Commands Group" />
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Description"
          DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started." />
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

**code.js**

```
  await Office.ribbon.requestUpdate({
    tabs: [
      {
        id: 'ContextMenuCell',
        groups: [{
          id: "myMenu",
          controls: [{
            id: "myMenuItemID",
            enabled: false
          }]
        }]

      }
    ],
```

can anyone guide me on this **error**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3422 .

Note, you can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.